# Aggregate function help - mssql

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

Need some help getting sales by month for a customer and his agent channel

have a customer table that looks something like this

customer table:
    cust_id bigint,
    agent_id bigint,
    name varchar(200),
    customer_level int,
    date_signed datetime

a customer level = 1 a customer who can transact; agent_id = null
a customer_level = 2 an agent of a level_1 customer and can transact, level_1 cust_id = level_2 agent_id

Transaction table:
    tx_id bigint,
    tx_date datetime,
    description varchar(200),
    amount money,
    cust_id bigint

## SQL

```
SELECT datepart(month, t.tx_date) AS TX_MONTH
    ,CASE 
        WHEN c.customer_level = 2
            THEN a.NAME
        ELSE c.NAME
        END AS CUSTOMER
    ,count(t.amount)
    ,sum(t.amount)
FROM TRANSACTION t
INNER JOIN customer c ON t.cust_id = c.cust_id
LEFT JOIN customer a ON c.agent_id = a.cust_id
WHERE t.tx_date >= '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY datepart(month, t.tx_date)
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

===

for starters this sql wont work need to group by c.name, a.name

however the intended result will not be realised....which is to get monthly sales by a customer and his agent channel

HELP!

Comment: Trying to understand.  In your query, you are only selecting the month and your customer, no agent channel.  To make your query work, with the select you currently have, you need to group by exactly what you are selecting.  So, you need to group by your datepart... and your case statement.

Comment: @andrew ..... agreed.... the idea behind the script is to get a aggregate sales figure by month for a customer and all his agents....if i group by customer and agent.....then it will not give the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions I'm making:

1. You will likely want year as part of the result set in case this report is used across the new year boundary.
2. You may want to pass parameters to this query, I'm going to use @CustID BIGINT, and @StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE to help limit rows for performance reasons in the case of large result sets.
3. You will need to group by the expression used in the select clause.

Try this:

```
    SELECT MONTH(t.tx_date) AS TX_MONTH, YEAR(t.tx_date) AS TX_YEAR
        ,CASE 
            WHEN c.customer_level = 2
                THEN a.NAME
            ELSE c.NAME
        END AS CUSTOMER
        ,count(t.amount)
        ,sum(t.amount)
    FROM TRANSACTION t
        INNER JOIN customer c ON t.cust_id = c.cust_id
        LEFT JOIN customer a ON c.agent_id = a.cust_id
    WHERE CAST(t.tx_date AS DATE) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
        AND c.cust_id = @CustID
    GROUP BY YEAR(t.tx_date), MONTH(t.tx_date)
        ,CASE 
            WHEN c.customer_level = 2
                THEN a.NAME
            ELSE c.NAME
        END
    ORDER BY YEAR(t.tx_date), MONTH(t.tx_date)
```

This should give you a result set with Year, Month of transactions the Agent name or Customer Name, for a given customer between two dates.